# How to show some store in google maps for xamarin android

Tags: c#, android, google-maps, xamarin.android, google-maps-android-api-2

I want to my maps add markers from store that i searched. example i want my maps only shows all seven eleven store in england and then i want to find the nearest seven eleven in my curent location. Is there any method to do that or reference that i was looking for. here is my current code

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Gms.Maps;
using Android.Gms.Maps.Model;
using System;

namespace _Map
{
    [Activity(Label = "_Map", Icon = "@drawable/icon", MainLauncher =true)]

    public class MainActivity : Activity, IOnMapReadyCallback
    {
        private GoogleMap GMap;
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource  
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
            SetUpMap();
        }
        private void SetUpMap()
        {
            if (GMap == null)
            {
                FragmentManager.FindFragmentById<MapFragment>(Resource.Id.googlemap).GetMapAsync(this);
            }
        }
        public void OnMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)
        {
            this.GMap = googleMap;
            GMap.UiSettings.ZoomControlsEnabled = true;

            BitmapDescriptor image = BitmapDescriptorFactory.FromResource(Resource.Drawable.gramed);

            LatLng latlng = new LatLng(Convert.ToDouble(-6.196279), Convert.ToDouble(106.822369));
            LatLng latlng2 = new LatLng(Convert.ToDouble(-6.220489), Convert.ToDouble(106.814349));
            LatLng latlng3 = new LatLng(Convert.ToDouble(-6.163067), Convert.ToDouble(106.832605));
            CameraUpdate camera = CameraUpdateFactory.NewLatLngZoom(latlng, 15);
            GMap.MoveCamera(camera);


            MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions()
                        .SetPosition(latlng)
                        .SetIcon(image)
                        .SetSnippet("Open 9AM-11PM")
                        .SetTitle("Gramedia");

            GMap.AddMarker(options);


            MarkerOptions options1 = new MarkerOptions()
                .SetPosition(latlng2)
                .SetIcon(image)
                .SetTitle("Gramedia 2")
                .SetSnippet("Open 8AM - 10PM");
            GMap.AddMarker(options1);

            MarkerOptions options2 = new MarkerOptions()
                .SetPosition(latlng3)
                .SetIcon(image)
                .SetSnippet("Open 8AM-9PM")
                .SetTitle("Gramedia 3");
            GMap.AddMarker(options2);
        }
    }

}
```

as you can see i have to add the marker manualy for each store, there is like a hundred store that i supposed to add in the map. is there any easy way to do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to my maps add markers from store that i searched. example i want my maps only shows all seven eleven store in England and then i want to find the nearest seven eleven in my current location. Is there any method to do that or reference that i was looking for.

You can use the Nearby search of [Place Search API](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search). By filtering [place types](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/supported_types), you can restrict your search results to store. And after getting the search results, you can pick seven or eleven stores that are nearest to your location and add markers to those seven stores.